# Manually set breaks and keep equal distance between them

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I'd like to plot a dataset that consists of two vectors of length 100. The mean difference of the vectors being high and the variance of each of them being considerably smaller, it is quite difficult to plot both vectors and still be able to see the variation within each vector.

What I'd like to be able to manually set the breaks so that we could both see the difference between the vectors and within them.

Consider this data set

```
a=rnorm(100,sd=0.005)+1
b=rnorm(100,sd=0.005)+10
vec = c(a,b)
```

Neither `plot(vec)` nor `plot(vec,log="y")` gives satisfying results, as it is not possible to distinguish the variation within the vector (see picture).

[image]

I'd like the breaks on the y-axis to be `(min(a), max(a), 5, min(b), max(b))` (and get equal distance between them). How could one achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, a simple transformation of the data in each part of the vector might be enough:

```
vec2 <- c( (a - min(a))/ (max(a)-min(a)) , 3 + (b - min(b))/ (max(b)-min(b))  ) 
plot(vec2, axes=F)
box()
axis(1)
axis(2, at=c(0,1,2,3,4), labels = round(c(min(a), max(a), 5, min(b), max(b)),2))
```

[image]

Alternative approaches might be a custom transformation in ggplot, a secondary axis in ggplot, breaking the graph into facets, or using ggbreak.